# jQuery slider causing code to stop working

Tags: php, jquery

Hello fellow code ninjas, I have been playing around with this nifty [jQuery price range slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range)

and once I implemented it, it caused my text boxes, choose image function, and Jquery drag & drop elements to stop working :(

I looked through the code and can't seem to find what went wrong.

The page I put it on is here: https://www.picklify.com/feed/beta/

And you will see the price range slider in the "Seller's Search" box at the bottom. If you view my page source you can see all the code there.

Help me from pulling out my hair, and thank you! :)

Comment: Unrelated problem, `https://www.picklify.com/resources/demos/style.css` returns 404.

Comment: i uploaded a file for this, thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including jQuery.js twice in page. Second version wipes out plugins that are registered to first version which throws error since those plugin functions no longer exist. Delete second version so jQuery loads before all plugns

Comment: thanks so much for the answer, I couldn't figure this out, and for it to be so simple, at least now I'll know to double check for redundant code includes.  I'm new at this so thank you!!

Comment: really easy to use a browser console to look at errors thrown... the type of error would see is likely easily found in web search... or provides more detail here when posting questions- just an FYI

Comment: do you mean the chrome browser console for example where I can inspect elements?  What do you mean about the error being found in web search, like searching on Google for the problem I was having?  I didn't know I was using the js code twice.

Answer (score 2):

Below your comment `<!-- BEGIN jquery price range slider -->`, you are re-including jQuery and jQuery UI. Remove those references and combine the inline script in your head.

Comment: aahh that seems to have done the trick, I didn't even see that! you guys rock! :)